# xls-to-json not working in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, excel

I want to convert `.xls` file in JSON format I have used `xls-to-json` module for the same.

when I used `xlsx-to-json` module it is working fine. but I don't want to read `.xlsx file`. it is giving me an error with :

`TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter.`

I am unable to find an error. is there any other module to convert .xls file in JSON.

```
here is my code :
 var node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
 app.get('/file',function(req,res){
        node_xj({
            input: 'file.xls',  // input xls
            output: "output.json", // output json
            sheet: "sheetname",  // specific sheetname
        }, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to read only `xls` file? and that file will come dynamically?

Comment: yes. i want to read only xls file which will come dynamically

Answer (score 0):

That package supports only the new xlsx format used by MS Excel.

The easiest option would be to save the file as comma-delimited csv file (as the format is available in most softwares) and use a csv to json converter.

There's a nice one here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module to get `file extension`, and if the file extension is match then execute the parsing code

```
var node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
var path = require('path');
app.get('/file', function(req, res) {
  //Give file name with extension e.g, file.xls
  if (path.extname('file.xls') === '.xls') {
    node_xj({
      input: 'file.xls', // input xls
      output: "output.json", // output json
      sheet: "sheetname", // specific sheetname
    }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

***Update***

This is not an issue of this module, but the issue comes from third-party module dependency [xlsjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsjs)

here is the [opened issue](https://github.com/DataGarage/node-xls-json/issues/14) you can see the updates

Comment: it is not going in if condition.

Comment: still it is showing same error : TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter

Comment: Whats you `node.js` version?

Comment: There are some issue on third party module dependency, see the updated answer

Comment: i am unable to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [module](https://github.com/circabs/xl-json), note I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

The xls-to-json-lc's package has been merged into xlsx-to-json-lc's package. Just use the Xlsx for both types of extensions and will work fine.